# How to calculate age from current year MySQL WorkBench

Tags: mysql

I need to calculate the age of dogs that are alive. Doing that, I also need to use a function to retrieve the current year. The age has to be displayed in a separate table in the select statement. In the 'BORN' column of the table, there are four dogs that I have to retrieve there age. Born years are (if this matters?) 2007, 2009, 2005, 2010. Think I have to implement the 'CURDATE' and 'YEAR' functions in here, just not sure on how to do that properly. I've given it a fair few attempts, but it never runs :(

```
Select dog_id,
Name,
From Dogs
Order by dog_id
```

Comment: please provide a table structure. Its really hard to understand what's there in your Table

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have the years stored, this will only be an approximation of the real age.

```
select dog_id, Name, year(curdate()) - born as age
From Dogs 
Order by dog_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), dob)), "%Y")+0 AS age from Yourtable
```

Please Check https://goharsahi.wordpress.com/2007/08/18/calculating-age-from-date-of-birth-in-mysql/ for reference